# Creating multiple instances of Angular2 app as Child to Parent in Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I am trying to create a sticky notes kind of desktop application using Electron.

I created a transparent **MainWindow** and created 2 **childWindow**s which load the same **index.html** file of the Angular2 app.

**Qs:** How do i interact with the ChildWindow considering that the number of ChildWindows can vary (added or removed).

As of now when i close the 2 ChildWindows the electron app still does not shut down because there is no way to close the Main Window.

I need to detect that all child Window instances have been closed which should trigger the `app.on('window-all-closed',function() {`.... method.

Any suggestions

**Electron app** main.js

```
var electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
var app = electron.app;
// Module to create native browser window.
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
var mainWindow;
var children = [];
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    //mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({fullscreen: true, frame: false, transparent: true})
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        fullscreen: true,
        frame: false,
        transparent: true
    });
    // Adding first sticky
    children.push(new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, frame: false, parent: mainWindow }));
    OpenChildInstance(children[0]);
    AddChild();
    function AddChild() {
        var childWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, frame: false, parent: mainWindow });
        OpenChildInstance(childWindow);
        children.push(childWindow);
    }
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    function OpenChildInstance(childWindow) {
        childWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/index.html");
        childWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
    children.forEach(AttachOnClosed);
    function AttachOnClosed(element, index, array) {
        element.on('closed', function () {
            children[index] = null;
            if (children == []) {
                if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
                    app.quit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Make window click through
    mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
    // Open the DevTools.
    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
app.on('activate', function () {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Comment: try adding a counter which counts child window instances. Add counter while creating , minus counter while closing. Also on closing check if counter reached 0, if so close the main one